# Why do I see random read errors with Python BaseHTTPServer?

Tags: python, http, sockets, concurrency, mocking

I have Python code that calls external HTTP services. I want to test this code by setting up mock HTTP servers that imitate those external services. I do this by starting a `BaseHTTPServer` in a separate thread, and then calling that server from the main thread. It looks like this:

```
import BaseHTTPServer, httplib, threading, time

class MockHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write('{"result": "success"}')

class ServerThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        svr = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('127.0.0.1', 8540), MockHandler)
        svr.handle_request()

ServerThread().start()
time.sleep(0.1)             # Give the thread some time to get up

conn = httplib.HTTPConnection('127.0.0.1', 8540)
conn.request('POST', '/', 'foo=bar&baz=qux')
resp_body = conn.getresponse().read()
```

However, some of the requests fail in the `read()` call, with `socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer`. I can reproduce it, with varying frequency, on several machines with Python 2.6, though not with 2.7.

But the most interesting thing is, if I don’t send the POST data (i.e. if I omit the third argument to `conn.request()`), the error does not occur.

What could this be?

Alternatively, is there another quick and easy way to set up mock HTTP servers in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"...in a separate thread, and then calling that server from the main thread."

Don't use threads for this kind of thing.

Use processes.   `subprocess.Popen` (and your operating system's normal features) will do a much, much better job of assuring that this works properly.

Comment: @David Wolever: They aren't.  Threads share a lot of I/O resources.  When one thread is waiting for a read, the other threads may not necessarily get scheduled, leaving the HTTP libraries to provide weird connection reset by peer status messages.  Processes share nothing, allowing the I/O to proceed only OS-level scheduling considerations.  Threads should be used only for compute-intensive things, not I/O things.  This is clearly I/O intensive.

Comment: Thank you. I rewrote my mock server around `multiprocessing`, using `Queue` to pass the server’s opinion of the request back to the test cases. This works, and is almost as easy as `threading`. However, I must admit I don’t understand the cause of this issue. Moreover I used to believe that threads in Python were useless for compute-intensive tasks because of the GIL—the opposite of what you say. I guess I need to read some illuminating docs.

Comment: @Vasiliy Faronov: "useless for compute-intensive tasks because of the GIL".  Partially true.  Not entirely true.  It's not a trivial distinction.  However, you can easily avoid wasting time trying to work with threads in general.  Use `multiprocessing`.